# gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert Returns Truncated Permissions Resource

Tags: google-drive-api

When making a permissions update call using `gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert` I appear to be getting a truncated response, or at least not the anticipated `permission resource`.

The parsed response looks like this:

```
{
     "kind": "drive#permission",
     "etag": ...,
     "id": ...,
     "selfLink": ...,
     "result": {
          "kind": ...,
          "etag": ...,
          "id": ...,
          "selfLink": ...
    }
}
```

Here is how I am making the call:

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.insert({
    fileId: myFileId,
    resource: {
        value:"example@gmail.com",
        type:"user",
        role:"writer"
    }
});

request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
});
```

Any ideas why I am getting this and not a full [permissions resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions#resource)?

Comment: Maybe you could try sending the request in this API explorer in this page : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert#examples and I also see that there is a fields( Selector specifying which fields to include in a partial response.) parameter where you can select which fields to be included in the partial response. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal occurrence. There is no guarantee that the resource will be fully populated because the HTTP response may be sent without waiting for all operations to occur. If you need the full resource, do a [permissions.get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/get) after doing the insert.